# Your Config file threw an error from: cypress.config.js we stopped running your tests because your config file crashed

Tags: cucumber, cypress, package.json, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

Facing this error after cypress cucumber configuration in Cypress 10.6.0 version, I installed cypress and cucumber,added the required dependencies and did other required configurations still when I am running the feature file I am getting this error

Your Config file threw an error from: cypress.config.js we stopped running your tests because your config file crashed